# Handle Frequently updated geo data in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, time-series

I have the location(geo points) data  updated every 5 minutes for millions of users. We have to search users with specific attributes(age/interests/languages) & in particular geo range. Wanted to understand the right strategy to store such data in Elastic.

### Option1

Create user document with following keys

- user Metadata & attributes (age, interests, languages, salary etc around 8-10 searchable attributes)
- Live location (changing every few minutes)

```
"liveLocation" : {
"type" : "Point",
"coordinates" : [-72.333077, 30.856567]
}
```

- location data  - multiple addresses - home address, work address etc along with geo points. (not updated frequently)  -

```
"addresses" :
 [
    {
        "type" : "home",
        "address" : "first floor, xyz, near landmark",
        "city" : "Newyork",
        "country" : "Country", 
        "zipcode" : "US1029", 
        "location" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [-73.856077, 40.848447]
    },
    {
     ... more atype of addresses
    }
 ]
```

We want to perform geo search queries over all the geo type fields. My worry  - live location for users will be updated quite frequently. Is this a viable approach ?

### Option2

- Treat every location update as a time series data and insert a new document. This will avoid updating the documents. instead will insert new documents for each user every few minutes.

Problems -

- While searching all the users(home/office/live location)  in a particular geo range, I have to consider only the **last updated documents for each user** . How to do that in elastic ?
- We have to search users with specific attributes(age/interests/language) & in particular geo range. If option2 is preferable should user attribute-metadata & location updates be treated as parent-child relationship or some other approach?
- In Conclusion - What should be the right approach .

Comment: You asked multiple questions in one question, would advise you to break these in smaller questions if you can

Comment: ok, I have tried to summarize it better, actually all are quite related queries.

Comment: loks like still it didn't help you as there is no comment from other community members ☹️

Comment: Yes :( .  I am going towards Option1 only. Need to find the right balance of frequency of updates of the location.

Comment: so finally got some time to go through your requirements and certainly option 1 is better reasons ) 1, as live location is updated in few seconds and you will end up creating millions of **Similar docs** for a single user. 2) having huge and duplicate records isn't good for ES perf.